# DUP packet response from the target

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, ip-address, ping

I am using Virtual machine containing linux RTOS as a guest and windows as the host OS. I am trying to ping from VM to the target. I am getting the response as below -

```
PING 192.168.0.8 (192.168.0.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 Redirect Network(New nexthop: 192.168.0.8)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=1005 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=1005 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=4.60 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=4.60 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=63 time=1005 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=63 time=1005 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=63 time=4.61 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=63 time=4.62 ms (DUP!)
From 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=3 Redirect Network(New nexthop: 192.168.0.8)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=2.20 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=2.21 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=63 time=2.22 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=63 time=2.22 ms (DUP!)
From 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=4 Redirect Network(New nexthop: 192.168.0.8)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=2.35 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=2.36 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=63 time=2.36 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=63 time=2.37 ms (DUP!)
```

what is the reason for above ?

Comment: What's the machine with IP `192.168.0.1` ? It seems your routing tables isn't set up properly since you get an ICMP redirect, and/or possibly there's dublicate IP addresses somewhere on your network.

Comment: 192.168.0.1 is the host system. 0.8 is target and guest is 0.5